# Is there a color that meets the WCAG 2.0 contrast requirements for both black and white (Level AA)?

Tags: colors, contrast, wcag2.0

I would like to find a color that meets the WCAG 2.0 (Level AA) contrast requirements for black (`#000`) as well as the contrast for white (`#FFF`).

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast

> "1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum): The visual presentation of text and images of text has a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1, except for the following: (Level AA)"

I don't understand what the ratio means enough to make an educated guess. Does such a color even exist? I can't find an answer either way.

Comment: According to http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html, the color #767676 meets the AA requirements.

Comment: @JQNinja Another color contrast tool that may help: http://accessible-colors.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to rdoyle for pointing this out.

> According to snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html, the color #767676 meets the AA requirements.